# How to add an engine in TexShop 4.27 on MacOS 10.14.5 bib2gls, arara

Tags: texshop, arara, bib2gls, engine

I am new to Tex.
I am trying to build a glossary using the package glossaries-extra. I am drawing my abbreviations list from a .bib file using GlsXtrLoadResources. Unfortunately I cannot seem to add the bib2gls engine or the arara engine. I have copied and pasted the arara engine file in the Engines folder and converted to an executable file but still doesn't seem to work? Wondering what I am doing wrong.

How do I run bib2gls in TexShop???

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: ps am running Java 8 Update 211

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should probably add some more information to your question, e.g. a small example document, the commands you did run, compilations logs/error messages or whatever is necessary for others to replicate the issue.

Comment: Are the engine files named with an extension `.engine`? Also, I think you may need to restart TeXShop.

Comment: Thanks Siracusa and Peter Grill.

Comment: The file is in pathname: /Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/TeXShop/Engines and the file is arara.engine the code looks like:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
arara -v "$1"

Comment: I found instructions to create a glossary.engine file to use bib2gls but it also doesn't work. I am just having trouble figuring out how set up the front end to run bib2gls after I run pdftex

Comment: I also followed the following instructions: https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/#texshop (about 3/4 down the page under TexShop) but also did not work... Please help

Comment: When I try to run bib2gls in Terminal I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/dickimawbooks/bib2gls/Bib2Gls : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0